# Deploying Contract with React

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, react

I am trying to deploy a contract on react. But I can't seem to pull it off :(

This is my code:

```
this.myContract.deploy({
          data:[big boi bytecode here],
          arguments: ['name', 'description', 20, 20]
      });
```

And this is the error I am receiving: "TypeError: this.gamechanger.deploy is not a function"

I have also tried using:

```
this.myContract.deployed().then(() => [...]
```

However, it would not deploy.

How should I go about doing this? Help would be insanely appreciated!

P.s. I am using Web3 version 1.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this.myContract is undefined in your scope.

Also you forgot `.send()` to deploy a contract

Example:

```
this.myContract.deploy({
   data:[big boi bytecode here], // Don't forget about '0x' on the start of bytecode
   arguments: ['name', 'description', 20, 20]
}).send({ from: account });
```